# HERE Tour Planning Issue REACHABLE_CONSTRAINT - Location unreachable. Is there a way to add a tolerance?

Tags: location, here-tourplanning

I want to optimize a tour on https://tourplanning.hereapi.com/v3/problems (https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/3.8.0/api-reference-swagger.html). Now I have a job with a geolocation that cannot be navigated to. I get the error REACHABLE_CONSTRAINT for the unassigned jobs. If I set the geolocation to a few houses on the same street, the optimization works fine for all jobs.
Now my question: Is there a way to set a radius for the geolocation so that the optimization can still be successfully assigned, so that you are e.g. 100 meters away from the desired address of the workplace?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to define the tolerance radius for the location. We may plan to work on this in the future.

On the other note, the location can be unreachable due to some temporary traffic event nearby. It may cause the vehicle not to be able to reach that location. In most cases, if historicalOnly traffic mode is used, the location may become reachable if it was unreachable due to some temporary traffic event. To use this, define fleet.traffic = historicalOnly